# Unexpected white space after SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, adodb, vba

Seem to be getting unexpected white space when calling the stored procedure from VBA in Excel using ADODB object. The issue does not occur when running the procedure from SQL Server Management Studio.

```
exec usp_testloginalert '2015-11-29 00:00:00','2015-11-30 00:00:00',N'screen'
```

UPDATE

Code from vba

```
Function querylogs(ByVal todate As Date, ByVal fromdate As Date, ByVal desc As String)
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmdProd As ADODB.command
Dim prs As New ADODB.Recordset

sQuery = "usp_testloginalert"
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn
    .Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
    sConnection = "dbconn"
    .ConnectionString = sConnection
    .ConnectionTimeout = 1000
    .CommandTimeout = 1000
End With
cn.Open sConnection

Set cmdProd = New ADODB.command
With cmdProd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "usp_testloginalert"
    .CommandTimeout = 1000
End With
Dim prmFromDate As ADODB.Parameter
Set prmFromDate = cmdProd.CreateParameter("@FromDate", adDBDate,adParamInput)
prmFromDate.Value = fromdate
cmdProd.Parameters.Append prmFromDate

Dim prmToDate As ADODB.Parameter
Set prmToDate = cmdProd.CreateParameter("@ToDate", adDBDate, adParamInput)
prmToDate.Value = todate
cmdProd.Parameters.Append prmToDate

Dim prmDescritpion As ADODB.Parameter
cmdProd.Parameters.Append cmdProd.CreateParameter("Descritpion",adBSTR,adParamInput, 100, desc)

Set prs = New Recordset
prs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
prs.Open cmdProd.Execute

Application.EnableCancelKey = True
cn.Close

Set querylogs = prs
End Function
```

Comment: Show your code that call SP

Comment: I suppose that you have parameter with `CHAR` datatype

Comment: no using varchar(200) for desc

Comment: @jennous Not helpful, no need to be here if it not solve the problem. SO should stay as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issues resolved, set the parameter length to the length of the variable passed.

Dim lendesc As Integer

```
lendesc = Len(desc) + 1

Dim prmDescritpion As ADODB.Parameter
cmdProd.Parameters.Append cmdProd.CreateParameter("Descritpion", adBSTR,adParamInput, lendesc, desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer when we not see code of your procedure, but I can suggest you to use [LTRIM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) and [RTRIM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) to remove leading/trailing blanks.

In following: `LTRIM(RTRIM( /* character_xpression */ ))`

**UPDATE**

If It's not SQL issue, try to check for related posts:

[Remove leading or trailing spaces in an entire column of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578397/remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-an-entire-column-of-data)

[Delete blanks from start and end of a string in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652952/delete-blanks-from-start-and-end-of-a-string-in-vba)

http://www.excelitems.com/2009/03/remove-extra-spaces-from-cell-value.html

Comment: already using LTRIM and RTRIM in procedure , we have fully tested the stored procedure, the issues seem to be on the vba end